# Identification of a probable sylviidae

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

One summer (August) I was in Bulgaria (Dobrich province) and in the middle of the city I take picture of this bird:

[image: sylviidae]
[image: sylviidae]
[image: sylviidae]

He was making a sound like "Tchek-tchek" like the sound of a `Eastern Olivaceous Warbler` (lat. `Iduna Pallida`) but the greenish color make me think it is more a `Icterine Warbler` (lat. `Hippolais icterina`).
I found a song similar to the bird I saw on [this page](http://www.oiseaux.net/oiseaux/hypolais.pale.html) (second record).

It could also be a `Common Chiffchaff` (lat. `Phylloscopus collybita`) or a `Willow Warbler` (lat. `Phylloscopus trochilus`) as they are very common but the length of the tail make me feel it more one of the above (or another one) and the sound does not seem to fit.

Anyone can help on identification of this bird?

Comment: Are you sure it is always the same bird? The one in the first pictures seems very different: white edges on the wing, legs of a different color, less prominent supercilium.

Comment: I thought first it was the same, but after your remarks I noticed the pictures are done on the same tree but two different days. What confused me is the sound of the bird, but I can admit I did not see them singing in front of me.

Comment: Warbler can be difficult at the beginning that's why now they are my favorite to identify, I provided the correct answer below, if you have any question feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first picture is an Icterine warbler. Because of the yellowish plumage (never in the eastern olivaceous) and the with fringes of tertiary characteristic of the species and never present in the genus Phylloscopus. Also the color of the leg, greish-bluish is quite specific of the Icterine.

[image]

The second and third picture are of a Willow warbler (*Phylloscopus trochilus*). The legs are pale compared to a chiffchaff and the primary projection (the length of the primaries that pass the tertiary) is extremely long and very typical of the willow warbler. You can see the difference in the image below.
 [Here a useful webpage](http://www.dublinbirding.ie/pages/features/chiff-willow.htm)

[image]

Comment: please provide reputable citations to back up your claims. Thanks

Comment: There is no citation involved in identifying birds. In Europe this is the best guide https://www.amazon.com/Collins-Bird-Guide-Lars-Svensson/dp/0007268149          But a guide is not enough to identify birds, the field experience is essential (I have been birdwatching for 20 years).